# Parse netstat command to get ports

Tags: bash, parsing

When i run netstat i have the following outpout :

```
$ netstat -lnp --inet                                                                 
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State        PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:51413           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN       6155/transmission-g 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56424         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN       450/weechat         
netstat: no support for `AF INET (sctp)' on this system.
```

I want to have the list of the ports using only bash (with python it would be easier). I have this :

```
$ netstat -lnp --inet | cut -d' ' -f45-50 | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'                
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
netstat: no support for `AF INET (sctp)' on this system.


6155
450
```

But i can't get rid of the text. Any help ?

Comment: That's probably standard error. Redirect it `2>/dev/null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines:

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
```

Are sent to stderr instead of stdout so you can get rid of them by sending stderr to /dev/null instead of letting it be printed in the console.

As in:

```
$ netstat -lnp --inet 2>/dev/null| cut -d' ' -f45-50 | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'
```

BTW, piping through egrep "\w" will get rid of the empty lines.

```
$ netstat -lnp --inet 2>/dev/null| cut -d' ' -f45-50 | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' | egrep "\w"
```

Answer (score 4):

More robust with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
netstat -lnp --inet | awk -F'LISTEN *|/' '/^(tcp|udp)/{print $2}' file
6155
450
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
netstat -lnp --inet | grep -E 'tcp|udp' | cut -d' ' -f45-50 | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'
```

Comment: This returns the PID, not the port.